# Compare strings, use the shorter character string

Tags: php, web-scraping, conditional-statements

I'm a beginning programmer trying to make a simple application that just scrapes a website and returns values.

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple, but after searching and trying, have given up to just ask.

With my scraper, I return three variables: **$title1**, **$title2**, and **$title3**. All of the $title's come from different methods of me trying to find the name of the article. Ideally, I'd just have to look for one and be done, but some websites store data differently (some through meta tags, hidden divs, elements, etc).

I need a way to do the following pseudo code:

```
if $title1, $title2, $title3 != null { // don't count a string if it is null

    $title1_stringlength = string_length($title1) //find string length of the $titles
    $title2_stringlength = string_length($title2)
    $title3_stringlength = string_length($title3)

    $realtitle = $lowestvalueofstringlength; // $realtitle gets whichever $title is shortest in length, not counting any null $title's

}
```

Here's an example of why I need to do this:

```
echo $title1; //echoes "Exercise Daily"
echo $title2; //echoes "null"
echo $title3; //echoes "Exercise Daily - And More advice on SaveTheTwinkie.org"
$realtitle = $title1;//should be $title1 because it was shortest that wasn't null

//or a different example from another site

echo $title1; //echoes "Wow look at this Article Title!"
echo $title2; //echoes "null"
echo $title3; //echoes "Wow look at this Article Title! - from StupidArticles.tv"
$realtitle = $title1;//should be $title1 because it was shortest that wasn't null
```

So my code would look for the shortest $title in string length (that wasn't null) and give the value to $realtitle.

Thanks for any and all help! If you need more details, just ask!

---

EDIT

---

heres my complete code: It works until one of the $title's is "", then $realtitle becomes "" as well

```
<?php

$sites_html = file_get_contents($url);

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($sites_html);
$title1 = null; //reset
$title2 = null; //reset
$title3 = null; //reset

//Get all meta tags and loop through them.
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:title'){ 
        //Assign the value from content attribute to $title1
        $title1 = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('itemprop')=='name'){
        $title2 = $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('class')=='fn'){
        $title3 = $div->nodeValue;
    }
}

$realtitle = array_reduce(array($title2, $title1, $title3), function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) && $a != 'null' && strlen($a) < strlen($b) ? $a : $b;
}, null);

    echo 'metaogtitle: '.$title1 . '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    echo 'name: '.$title2. '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    echo 'name2: '.$title3. '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    echo 'realtitle: '.$realtitle. '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
?>
```

Comment: Ehm, maybe a silly question, but what do you do if all three titles are "null"?

Comment: @hakre..I'm not sure, I'll have to figure it out. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Filter invalid values
$titles = array_filter($titles, function($title) { return $title && $title != 'null'; }); 
// Just  sort :)
usort ($titles, function ($left, $right) { return strlen($left) - strlen($right); });
echo $titles[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant that works with an unlimited number of strings:

```
$shortest = NULL;

$shortestReduce = function ($string) use (&$shortest) {

    if ( ($string === "null") || !($len = strlen($string))) {
        return $shortest;
    }

    if (!isset($shortest) || $len < strlen($shortest)) {
        $shortest = $string;
    }

    return $shortest;
};

$shortestReduce($string1);
$shortestReduce($string2);
$shortestReduce($string3);
# ...

echo $shortest; # "Exercise Daily"
```

This reduce allows you to apply the same function on multiple values generating one outcome, here the shortest string that is not `"null"`.

Comment: Actually there is no "map" step in your algorithm, only "reduce"

Comment: Thanks for your code it works perfectly...Is there a way to also not allow characters with 0 words be counted?

Comment: @Jake: Just add another condition like `and (strlen($string))`

Comment: @hakre...I tried again and tried a var_dump of $shortest and the value is null? Here's my code: `<?

$title1 = "hi";
$title2 = "hi stackoverflow";
$title3 = null;

$shortest = NULL;

$shortestMapReduce = function ($string) use (&$shortest) {
    if (
        ($string !== "null")
        and (strlen($string))
        and (strlen($string) < strlen($shortest))
    ) {
        $shortest = $string;
    }
    return $shortest;
};

$shortestMapReduce($title1);
$shortestMapReduce($title2);
$shortestMapReduce($title3);

echo $shortest;
var_dump($shortest);
?>`

Comment: There was a mistake indeed and I fixed it. Because it was NULL it was already shortest. So now I check with isset if it is NULL and then it will be initialized on first valid input string.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
function real_title($titles) {
    /* Gets array of titles.
       Return the shortest that isn't null.
    */

    $min_length = strlen($titles[0]);
    $real_title = $titles[0];

    foreach ($titles as $single_title) {
       $title_length = strlen($single_title);
       if (($title_length < $min_length) && ($title_length > 0)) {
                $min_length = $title_length;
                $real_title = $single_title;
        }
    }

    return $real_title;
}
```